# How to change class of valid form field - jQuery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I am using bassistance jQuery form validation plugin.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

I made a form with form fields and set rules;

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
          alert("submitted!");
        }
    });
    var validator = $("#testform").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "",
        },
        error: function(element) {
            element.addClass("error");
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#testform input{
  border: solid 2px black;
}
#testform input.error{
  border: solid 2px #CC0000;
}
#testform input.checked{
  border: solid 2px #094AB2;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="testform" name="testform">
<input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" value="">
<input id="field2" name="field2" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The error function is working alright. But the success function is not adding styles to input type=text, instead, default style appears (black border instead of blue). How can I solve this?

Here is the working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgUqE/)**

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link

Comment: I might be mistaken but the docs show nothing about error and success methods... the only reason the "error" class works is because by default, the validation plugin adds the class "error" In your code, try changing the classnam to something else, you'll see nothing happens. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CgUqE/1/

Comment: @vyx.ca, you are half-correct.  There is no such available option called `error`.  However, there is a `success` option and it can be a callback function.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `#testform input.checked` to `#testform input.valid`. I got this by submitting the form and check the class with developer tools or firebug. I saw the class name changed to valid and not checked

Here's a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CgUqE/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The `success` callback in the [`validate`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) method passes in the label for the given form input. If the label does not exist, it creates one.

The reason your code does not work as you intend is because your CSS assumes the `checked` class will be added to the input where it is actually added to the label.

The validate method automatically adds the `valid` class to inputs that pass validation and the `error` class those that do not. You can probably remove the specific callbacks unless you plan to perform additional tasks.

**CSS**

```
#testform input.valid{
  border: solid 2px #094AB2;
}
```

**JS**

```
var validator = $("#testform").validate({
    rules: {
        field1: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        field1: "",
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qHLuu/)**